# How can I override a javax.persistence.AttributeConverter

Tags: java, jpa

I have the problem that want to override an AttributeConverter in a subclass of an entity, but the defined converter in the subclass does not get called. According to the AttributeConverter documentation this should be the way, but it does not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate(value = true)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DISCRIMINATOR", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("ORDER")
public class Order implements Serializable
{
...
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_SERIALIZED", updatable = false)
    @Convert(converter = ProductConverter.class)
    protected Product product;
...
}
```

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CUSTOMER_ORDER")
@Convert(attributeName = "product", converter = CustomerProductConverter.class)
public class CustomerOrder extends Order
{
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems @Convert is not suitable to override an existing converter for a field of a superclass. I solved it in a different way. I injected a conversionService via CDI into the AttributeConverter of the superclass which I then can specialized.

```
@Converter
public class ProductConverter implements AttributeConverter<Product, String>
{
    ProductConverterService converterBean = null;

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Product attribute)
    {
        return getConverterService().convertToDatabaseColumn(attribute);
    }

    @Override
    public Product convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData)
    {
        return getConverterService().convertToEntityAttribute(dbData);
    }

    public ProductConverterService getConverterService()
    {
        if (converterBean == null)
        {
            //since ProductConverter is obiously not managed via CDI
            converterBean = CDI.current().select(ProductConverterService.class).get();
        }
        return converterBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's been a while, but do you remember more specifically how you did this? I need to do the same thing, but I'm unclear on how your ProductConverterService fits into this and how it's used over the base `ProductConverter`.

Comment: Looking at this again, I see how you did it. I unfortunately don't have access to the original implementation, so can't use this approach.